# Move Vaadin Slider

Tags: user-interface, vaadin

When I am invoking *slider.setValue()* it changes internal field *value* but not graphical representation of slider.
How to move slider to given value from server side? (For example on button click or something like this. Value change is invoked from other component.)

I have set *slider.setImmediate(true);* and after changing value called *slider.requestRepaint();* but this did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

You may check its' parent components and also check for the component which invokes this method in its' listener.